# Sanitize user input destined for database in PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection, code-injection, sanitization, sanitize

I have this code:

```
$query = "select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id  = $this->id";
```

I tried this code to sanitize it:

```
$query = sprintf("select id from votes where username = '$user' and article_id = $this->id", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($user), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

but I get this error for the mysql_real_escape lines:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'mexautos'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php on line 145 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php on line 145 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'mexautos'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php on line 146 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/mexautos/public_html/kiubbo/data/article.php on line 146
```

I get the user name here, I dont know if its safe enough:

```
function getUsername(){ return $this->username; }
```

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for this instead of `sprintf`

Comment: Great idea if the mysql interface supported them. He would need to switch to mysqli or PDO to use prepared statements.

Comment: If he's using PHP 5 or greater mysqli is included

Answer (score 8):

You need a mysql connection before you can use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I do have connection, I mean the site works and connects to the db, before inserting those lines. Thx.

Comment: That's not what the error is saying! Try using your link identifier as the second argument for your mysql_real_escape_strings and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what's causing your problem, but I believe the variables in your sprintf statement shouldn't be '$user' and '$this->id', but they should be '%s'

https://www.php.net/sprintf

Comment: Not to mention that he is trying to replace an article_id with a variable called $password.

Comment: Why use sprintf() at all - PHP has variable interpolation in strings. OTOH, a SQL statement built with sprintf() is just as unsafe as an interpolated one... Both methods should be avoided.

Comment: @Tomalak - I know, but was merely highlighting a bug in his code, not proposing a better method.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
> [function.mysql-real-escape-string]:
> Access denied for user
> 'mexautos'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
> [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A
> link to the server could not be
> established

Did you check the link ? Is it active ? You need to be connected before to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
Don't you forget to set the password ?

Try:

```
mysql -u mexautos -p
```

(type Enter if no password)

Also, check out your [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/sprintf) function, you need to use the %s to bind your variable

```
$a = 'Foo';
$b = 'Bar';
$foo = sprintf('Foo Bar %s %s', $a, $b);
```

Comment: Trying to connect throught the console is a way to check the privilege in raw way !

Answer (score 2):

You need a connection to use mysql_real_escape_string() because it uses the server's encoding type to help santitize.

Also the sprintf() should look something like this

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT id FROM votes WHERE username = '%s' and article_id = %d", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($user), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Comment: In mine, I wasn't sure if the id was necessarily an integer, so I just went with a string format.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a mature DB abstraction layer like [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.db.html) (there are tons of them out there). Implementing your own homebrew solution is not something I'd recommend for a production system.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said, not '$user' but '%s' and you need an open connection.

@Tomalak
sprintf is faster - that's the reason why to use it - it is a native C function.

Comment: sprintf is faster than what? When interacting with the database, that's not an especially good reason...

Comment: sprintf is faster than build PHP string interpolation, and it wasn't related whit the database subject, but whit Tomalak's comment.